# How we can identify from which component the event has been fired?

Tags: lightning, lightning-events

I have a scenario that I have an event called `AdviceEvent` registered by two different components `ParentCmp` and `FriendCmp`. And Third component called `PersonCmp` is handling both event.

The Question is if both `ParentCmp` and `FriendCmp` fire the same event at same time. at that situation `PersonCmp` should only listen to `ParentCmp`'s event.

And how can we identify from which component that event has been fired?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a string attribute in the event and set its value **fired from ParentCmp** when firing from ParentCmp  and **fired from FriendCmp** when fired from FriendCmp and in the listener object you can check the string value to know where is it fired from.